# sql query challenge for consolidating data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble writing the correct query. It would be appreciated if someone smarter ;) then me can help me.

It feels like it is easy, but I am just missing something....

so I have 2 tables;

`CarColors` and `CarColorTranslations`.

locally I have this for `CarColors` (parent is `CarDetail`)

[image]

Currently in this table we have the countrylocale where it belongs. 
Like the red box: (Id 5005 and 8006) are both related to cardetail 1 and only have a different name (other language of course)

But this is not the correct model. I need to get rid of `CountryLocaleId` and `Name` and put this in the CarColorTranslations table.

So first I had written this:

```
Insert into CarColorTranslations (Created, CreatedBy, Changed, ChangedBy, CarDetailId, CarColorId, CountryLocaleId, Name)
  select GETDATE(),'migrations', GETDATE(), 'migrations', cc.CarDetailId, cc.Id, cc.CountryLocaleId, Name from CarColors cc
```

this does write the rows to the other table; but I forgot one thing; i need to consolidate the data in carcolors; meaning; Id 5005 and 8006 need to be one; so i need to get rid of 8006 (or the other).
But at this point i will loose the parent from one record in CarColorTranslations..

CarColorTranslations has these few properties

```
CarDetailId (FK cardetail)
CarColorId (FK CarColor)
CountryLocaleId (FK countryLocale)
Name (Real translated value)
```

for consolidating the data and writing the queries to `CarColortranslations`; the combined key to match is `CarDetailId`, `HexColorCode`, `ColorCombinationId`, `Price`

as you see; the next record (9005), is a different color -for the same car- and does/should not match the other one.

Hope that it is clear.

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I will mention that I don't think the CarDetailId column is necessary in CarColorTranslations, as this is already available in its parent of CarColors.

For the INSERT, I think something like this is what you'd be looking for:

```
Insert into CarColorTranslations
(
    Created
    , CreatedBy
    , Changed
    , ChangedBy
    , CarDetailId
    , CarColorId
    , CountryLocaleId
    , Name
)

select
    GETDATE()
    ,'migrations'
    , GETDATE()
    , 'migrations'
    , cc.CarDetailId
    , MIN(cc.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY CarDetailId, HexColorCode, ColorCombinationId, Price)
    , cc.CountryLocaleId
    , Name
from CarColors cc
```

You could then look into doing something like a LEFT JOIN on CarColorId to DELETE CarColors records that are no longer in use.

Comment: totally agree on the cardetailId, feels like overkill... let me check the query!

Comment: add first glance it seems to work like a charm! thx!! Totally forgot about `PARTITION` gonna look into that one.

Comment: do you perhaps also have the query if i need to rollback? is there as well some fancy trick?

Comment: What do you need to roll back?

Comment: ow, sorry, forgot to tell the rest :innocent: after this query; my EF migration would drop the columns; countryLocaleId and Name. And obviously delete the record that is not needed anymore.

Comment: i have it; do it in 2 different queries though. One with the join, second where they are not joining.